# Can I specify multiple endpoints for Sendgrid Event Notification?

Tags: sendgrid

Is it possible to configure send grid account, that I can specify multiple Post Event URL Event notification. Or maybe is it possible to add multiple Event Notification apps?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Currently there's no way to have the Events Webhook POST events to multiple URLs.

You could write a script that'd repost data to as many URLs as you wanted and direct SendGrid to POST to it. For example, written in in PHP:

```php
// An array of the URLs you want to POST to:
$urls = array("http://mylocation1.com/event", "http://mylocation2.com/event");

$multi_handle = curl_multi_init();
$handles = array();
// Loop through each URL and create a cURL Handle for the URL
// The cURL handle will POST data that comes to this script to the url.
foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
    $handles[$key] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);

    curl_setopt($handles[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($multi_handle, $handles[$key]);
}

$running = null;
// Run through each cURL handle and execute it.
do {
    curl_multi_exec($multi_handle, $running);
} while ($running);

curl_multi_close($multi_handle);
```

---

**EDIT:** It's now recommended that you use [Reflector.io](https://reflector.io/) (another SendGrid Product) to have the webhook send to multiple destinations.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to use Event Notification for diffirent environment and it is not suitable for me using code for one environment that repost data to others, but anyway thanks.

Comment: reflector.io seems to be inactive as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

I also face the similar problem. In my case i had to update various environments (like stage/prod).

I choose **pub/sub** model.

- **Topic** = "Event-Webhook"
- **subscriber1** = stage cloud function
- **subscriber2** = prod cloud function.

**On sendgrid** under (mail setting > web hook):
I added publisher url for my topic.

Comment: Where can i find the publisher url for a topic?

Answer (score 0):

Updated! There is now an option to add multiple endpoints
https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook